# Using access vba to check if table column has null values

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to find if the specified column has null values or no data.if null values are present in the column then gives the message box to user saying column contain nulls. 
My vba

```
Dim sqlid As String
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim cdb As Database

Set cdb = CurrentDb
SQLEID = "SELECT * " & _
   "FROM table_1 ;"
'
  Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset(sqlid , dbOpenSnapshot)
   Do While Not rst.EOF
   If IsNull(rst.Fields("column1").Value) Then
   MsgBox "Has nulls"
   End If

   Loop   

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
```

But when i'm running this my access goes not responding. How do i check if the column has any nulls using vba

Comment: why not `SQLEID = "SELECT sum(1) FROM [table_1] WHERE IsNull([column1])"` and check what it returns? Or even shorter: `If DCount(1, "table_1", "IsNull([column1])")>0 Then`. Also check spelling: `SQLEID = "SELECT..."` but `cdb.OpenRecordset(sqlid ..)` and add `Option Explicit`

Comment: The query ** "SELECT sum(1) FROM [table_1] WHERE IsNull([column1])"** you specified is returns 68. Says item not found in the collection

Comment: if it returns 68, that means that you have 68 records with null values. What is the problem now?

Comment: I used **If DCount** it works perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hangs as your recordset is not being incremented, you need a MoveNext

```
Do While Not rst.EOF
   If IsNull(rst.Fields("column1").Value) Then
   MsgBox "Has nulls"
   End If
   rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Simoco had a better suggestion for accomplishing this,

```
If DCount(1, "table_1", "IsNull([column1])")>0 Then
MsgBox "Has nulls"
End If
```